# Proof: Solving a 9x9 sudoku is just as hard as determining whether there is a solution

Tags: sudoku

I have so show that, for the normal 9x9 sudoku, determining whether there is a solution is just as hard as computing a solution if it exists. I should do that by assuming i have a polynomial-time algorithm for checking whether a given sudoku is solvable and i then should explain how to obtain a polynomial-time algorithm for computing such a solution.

I have no idea how to show that using this "hint".

Comment: You speak of "polynomial-time", but polynomial in what? Pedantic answer: both finding a solution or finding whether it exists are done in $\mathcal{O}(1)$ time, since the sudoku is of constant size.

Comment: Oh yes of course. But how can I then explain how to get an algorithm for computing a solution?

Comment: @xxray What if you try all solutions somehow? Would something like backtracking work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you have 20 boxes filled out.

You put the number 1 in the first empty box and check if a solution exists. If yes, you put down 1 in the first empty box permanently and now you have a problem with 21 boxes filled out. If no, you put the number 2 in the first empty box and try again, up to 9. If you don't find a solution with 9 in the first empty box, then there is no solution.

In the worst case, you try numbers 1 to 9 in 81 empty boxes. So you check 729 times if a solution exists in the worst case. That's only a constant factor.

And as pseudynom says, if you take general n x n sudoku, then the factor 729 is just the special case for n=9. In general the factor is $n^3$.

Comment: In general, a $n \times n$ sudoku (standard sudoku has $n=9$) has $n$ rows, columns, boxes, and values. You would have to test $n^3$ possible values, which is a polynomial factor. Testing that a general sudoku has a solution is known to be NP-complete, and therefore finding a solution is FNP-complete.